# Check if $(\sqrt{1-x})^5$ is an element of the Sobolev space $W^1$ and $W^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the function:

$$f_1: (0,1) \to \mathbb R, \hspace{0.3cm} f_1(x)=(\sqrt{1-x})^5$$

Is this function an element of the Sobolev spaces $W^1((0,1))$ and $W^2\left((0,1)\right)$?

**My attempt:** I am trying to figure this out by using the definition from our lecture:

> The Sobolev space of order m with respect to $p=\infty$ is
>
> $$W^{m,\infty }(\Omega):= \{f \in L^\infty (\Omega) \hspace{0.3cm}\vert \hspace{0.3cm}D^{\alpha}f \in L^\infty(\Omega), \hspace{0.3cm} \forall \vert \alpha\vert\le m \}$$
> The norm in $W^{m,\infty }$ is
>
> $$\lVert u\rVert_{W^{m,\infty }}:=\max_{\lvert \alpha \rvert\le m} \lVert D^{\alpha} u\rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$$

I am not sure how to apply this definition. I also don't really understand what it says. Does it say that a function is part of the Sobolov $W^m$ if all derivatives up to the $m$-th derivative are bounded? So for $W^1$((0,1)) I was thinking of showing that:

$$\lVert (1-x)^{\frac{5}{2}}\rVert:=\max \lVert D^1f\rVert$$

is bounded. So we have:

$$\max \lVert-\frac{5}{2}(1-x)^{\frac{3}{2}} \rVert_{L^\infty}=\max \big(\sup(-\frac{5}{2}(1-x)^{\frac{3}{2}}) \big)=\frac{5}{2} < \infty$$

So it is bounded. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @Falcon Thank you for your response. I just wanted to clarify: If I want to check if it is an element of $W^2$ as well, then the first AND second derivatives would have to be bounded right? So, $$\max(\sup f'')=\max (\sup (\frac{15}{4}(1-x)^{1/2})) < \infty$$ Which shows that the second derivative is also bounded.

Comment: Yes that's is. Here the second derivative is clearly bounded but $f\notin W^{3, \infty}$ as the third derivative will behave like $(1 - x)^{-1/2}$ which blows up at $x = 1$.

Comment: Awesome, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your help :) (You can also post the comment(s) as an answer and I will accept it if you want.)